# c# Set value to a DataRow automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datarowview

What I want to do is to change value of row's forth cell if cell number 3 is changed. I have an EditEnding method for my grid. That's my method below. I don't really know how to finish it

that's the grid definition:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"... CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_EditEnding">
```

and the method:

```
private void dataGrid1_EditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    // initializing DataRowView from my datagrid
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.CurrentItem;

    // checking if there were any changes
    if (drv.Row[3, DataRowVersion.Original] != drv.Row[3])
    {
       //set value to cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Cell 3 is at index 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i did my stuff, just forget to post it here.

First I did it with EditEnding event, it looked like that:

```
private void dataGrid1_EditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.CurrentItem;

    if (drv.Row[3, DataRowVersion.Original] != drv.Row[3])
    {
       rowView.Row.SetField(4, /* my logic here */);
    }
}
```

The problem was it was adding the value only on second edit. Then I changed my idea and added a RowChanged event to my DataTable, which was like that:

```
    static void dtSP_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        bool temp = false;

        try
        {

            temp = e.Row[4, DataRowVersion.Original] == e.Row[4];
        }
        catch { }

        if (temp && int.Parse(e.Row[3].ToString()) != -1)
        {
            e.Row[4] = (/* my logic */);
        }
    }
```

The method was going into infinity loop (it was noticing, that fourth row had changed).

And then i saw this:
http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/05/26/datacolumn_expressions.html

I've ended with one line long code:

```
dtSP.Columns[4].Expression = "expression";
```

@blindmeis, I forgott to mention I use ADO.NET, sorry

Comment: I didn't know `CurrentItem` exists until now... Such a useful property.

Answer (score 0):

do not edit the datagridrow - edit the underlying object in wpf!

this mean when the bound property to cell 3 is changed then do your changes to the property bound to cell 4. INotifyPropertyChanged will notify your grid and will show your changes

Comment: why's that? When i set proper binding between DataGrid and DataTable, they should both edit when i change a row in DataTable

Comment: ?? you wrote that you wanna change a cell value when another cell has changed. all i say is that you should go the mvvm way and this mean: when a property(bind to cell3) changed, change the other property(cell 4) why you wanna do something in codebehind?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have logic to calculate cell4 value when cell3 is changed, then when property binded to column 3 is changed you should call INotifyPropertyChanged of property binded to column 3 & 4.