# Set value of DataRowView

Tags: c#, datarowview

I am looking to modify a DataRowView value from an event.

I have tried the following but it never changes the DataGridCheckBoxColumn

```
((DataRowView)repDataGrid.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[4] = true;
```

Comment: possible duplicate [Set value to a DataRow automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232466/c-sharp-set-value-to-a-datarow-automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ItemArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a new `object[]` which can be used to read the values. But you can't use it to set them. You can use the `DataRow` indexer:

```
((DataRowView)repDataGrid.SelectedItem).Row[4] = true;
```

If you wanted to use `ItemArray` to assign the values you have to re-assign it:

```
DataRow row = (DataRowView)repDataGrid.SelectedItem).Row;
object[] fields = row.ItemArray;
fields[4] = true;
row.ItemArray = fields;
```